# Create dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following:

```
select distinct
    loannumber, activedt, inactivedt
from 
    smd..TABLE_NAME
where 
    loannumber = '12345678'
```

I want to be able to create a column that contains a value for every month/date between the `activedt` and `inactivedt`. I have seen ideas where the dates are set as variables, but in this case, the dates are coming from the table for each record. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired results will reduce assumptions

Comment: A column should never contain multiple values. What I assume you really want is a row for each day between activedt and inactivedt? A calendar table may prove helpful but if you simply want those days a tally table would be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you MONTH increments.  However, if you want DAY, just change MM to DD within the CROSS APPLY

We're creating an ad-hoc tally table with `master..spt_values` , but any table of appropriate size will do

```
Declare @YourTable table (loannumber varchar(25),activedt date,inactivedt date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('12345678','2016-01-01','2017-12-31')

Select A.LoanNumber
      ,B.Date
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
       Select Top (DateDiff(MM,A.activedt,A.inactivedt)+1) Date=DateAdd(MM,Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null))-1,A.activedt) 
         From master..spt_values 
       ) B
```

Returns

```
LoanNumber  Date
12345678    2016-01-01
12345678    2016-02-01
12345678    2016-03-01
12345678    2016-04-01
12345678    2016-05-01
12345678    2016-06-01
12345678    2016-07-01
12345678    2016-08-01
12345678    2016-09-01
12345678    2016-10-01
12345678    2016-11-01
12345678    2016-12-01
12345678    2017-01-01
12345678    2017-02-01
12345678    2017-03-01
12345678    2017-04-01
12345678    2017-05-01
12345678    2017-06-01
12345678    2017-07-01
12345678    2017-08-01
12345678    2017-09-01
12345678    2017-10-01
12345678    2017-11-01
12345678    2017-12-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Date Tables, in this article, there is an extensive explanation, the idea is that you can use for this kind of scenario.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

With this table, you can do join between tables and use the date column.

Comment: Thanks.  But that situation is too complex for me. I would rather learn how to just make the query stop creating dates past the current date if the InactiveDt is NULL, or past the InactiveDt for each row if the InactiveDt has a value.

Answer (score 0):

You won't beat the performance of a physical date table, but if you have less than about 2000 days in between the inactive and active dates and just need basic queries ad-hoc against it, then consider `CROSS APPLY` against the spt_values table.

Since I wasn't sure if if active and inactive dates where always on or before (some cases with active > inactive, and others with inactive <= active), this should work for either case:

```
select distinct
    loannumber, activedt, inactivedt, dtvalue
from 
    smd..TABLE_NAME
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT DATEADD(DD, N.number, activedt) FROM spt_values N
            WHERE N.number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DD, activedt, inactivedt) AND activedt <= inactivedt
        UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DD, N.number, inactivedt) FROM spt_values N
            WHERE N.number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DD, inactivedt, activedt) AND activedt > inactivedt
    ) N (dtvalue)
where 
    loannumber = '12345678'
```

This produced the results below for a single record loan number from 1/3 to 1/5:

```
loannumber activedt   inactivedt dtvalue
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
12345678   2017-01-03 2017-01-05 2017-01-03
12345678   2017-01-03 2017-01-05 2017-01-04
12345678   2017-01-03 2017-01-05 2017-01-05
```

If you need to get beyond 2000, there are additional techniques to `UNION ALL` to generate appropriate row counts quickly.

Comment: Hi. I now have the following:g

Comment: How can I get the MO column to not create MO past the current date?    Declare YT table (loan varchar(25),activedt date,inactivedt date)
    Insert Into YT
    select 
    distinct
    loan, 
    activedt,
    inactivedt
    from
    tblONE A
    
    
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#RR') is not null Drop Table #RR
    select loan, 
    activedt,
    inactivedt,
    B.MO
    from 
    tableONE A
    
    cross apply
    (
    Select  MO=DateAdd(MM,Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null))-1,A.activedt) 
         From master..spt_values 
       ) B
    order by loan desc

Comment: You could add onto your last `WHERE` clause. In example from answer, it would be something like `AND dtvalue <= GETDATE()`